# Scrambling an array in idl

Tags: idl-programming-language, scramble

I was wondering if there is a module in idl that one can use to scramble an array of floating point numbers. I tried using scramble.pro but the problem is that it returns integers, and if I try to use float it doesn't return the exact numbers i entered, for example:

```
array = [2.3, 4.5, 5.7,8.9]
scr_array = scramble(array)
print, scr_array

output:

4 2 8 5
```

and if i use float:

```
print, float(scr_array)
```

the output is:

```
4.0000 2.0000 8.0000 5.0000
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [this](https://github.com/mgalloy/mglib/blob/master/src/analysis/mg_sample.pro) sampling routine, but asking for all the elements:

```
IDL> array = [2.3, 4.5, 5.7,8.9]
IDL> scramble_indices = mg_sample(4, 4)
IDL> print, scramble_indices
           1           3           0           2
IDL> print, array[scramble_indices]
      4.50000      8.90000      2.30000      5.70000
```

Comment: +1, but is there no way to do this in vanilla IDL? Matlab and R have this kind of functionality built-in.

Comment: I don't know of any builtin library routines to do this.

Answer (score 0):

scramble.pro assumes that the input is an integer array, so it always gives an integer array as its output. You can, however, use it to generate a random ordering of indices and feed these back into your original array (like mgalloy has done with mg_sample):

```
IDL> array = [2.3, 4.5, 5.7,8.9]
IDL> scr_array = array[scramble(n_elements(array))]
IDL> print, scr_array
      8.90000      2.30000      5.70000      4.50000
```

Here, `scramble` is given a single integer value, so it creates the random indices required. For vanilla IDL only, I often use the `randomu` and `sort` functions in combination to get the same effect:

```
IDL> array = [2.3, 4.5, 5.7,8.9]                  
IDL> indices = sort(randomu(seed, n_elements(array)))
IDL> scr_array = array[indices]                      
IDL> print, indices                                  
           3           2           0           1
IDL> print, scr_array                                
      8.90000      5.70000      2.30000      4.50000
```

Here, we're using `randomu` to generate a set of random numbers with the same number of elements as `array`, and `sort` gives us the indices that would put that random array in order. Together, they give you a random ordering of indices. Of course, you can put that on a single line too:

```
IDL> array = [2.3, 4.5, 5.7,8.9]                     
IDL> scr_array = array[sort(randomu(seed, n_elements(array)))]
IDL> print, scr_array
      5.70000      2.30000      8.90000      4.50000
```